# How to save a key press to variable with jnativehook

Tags: java, jnativehook

So this is probably an obvious question, but i am just wondering if there is a way to save a key press to a variable (like a char or a string). I am relatively new to java, I know how to use scanners and how to make hash codes, I got a login screen with no back button coded so yea making good progress, but with all that aside how do i save a key press to a variable?

Comment: Are you using a GUI or is this a Console (terminal) Application?

Comment: Like you set any value to any variable ... sorry for the vagueness of the comment, but it matches the vagueness of the question. Why are you using `jnativehook`?  That seems like a very specific requirement and to be honest, quite a technical one

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.2/doc/Keyboard.md) seems like a reasonable place to start, it shows you how to get the information from the API, from there it's just "standard" java variable assignment ... which raises more questions.  If you're not sure how that works, maybe something like JNI/native hooks is best put aside till you do

Comment: @DevilsHnd for now this is a terminal application

Comment: @MadProgrammer ya sorry if this is a lil vague but you can open a nativelistener and save the typed character to a variable? also i'm using jnativehook cause idk any other things that allow you to listen to keypresses lmao, please put me on if you know any other keypress detectors i could use. ^w^ ^w^ ^w^

Comment: [Language Basics: Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html); [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i feel confident i know how variables work, and i stay spamming the static keyword to use variables in inputmismatchexception circumventors. looking back to this question i think ima try to assign the variable in one of the methods and see if that works, maybe my mistake was trying to assign the variable in the main method lmaooo.

Comment: @MadProgrammer also wanna add, now reading the class members doc to understand how the private keyword even works.

Comment: @MadProgrammer well more like reading a quora thing lmao. still reading up on the private keyword doe.

Comment: @MadProgrammer omg i looked at the documentation you linked and i might've actually gotten somewhere, it's the vc events that hold the secret to actually assigning the values to a variable right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer wait but it's like the vc event won't save to the variable, i can make it do something if i push a key but idk how to translate that into saving it to a variable doe.

Comment: ok so i got it, all i needed to do was use an if statement where if a vc key is pressed, it'll do something (in my case, it adds to the array list)

so for my example:



`if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_W) {
   // typingDetector is my arraylist
            typingDetector.add(e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
   
        }`

hopefully the code formats right

Comment: well damn this code ain't newline correctly